# QWebView doesn't show checkbox element on OSX

Tags: macos, qt, checkbox, qwebview

I am working on a desktop application written wit Qt,  which is distributed to Windows and OSX. It contains a QWebView for loading a website which contains a checkbox (and more). This checkbox is a simple HTML element. On Windows there is no problem with it, but on OSX, the checkbox is not displayed in the WebView.

I checked the site on the same mac with Chrome and Safari, and the browsers had no problem displaying the checkbox.

What can cause this display issue, and is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This doesn't sound so much like a question as a bug report. Try https://bugreports.qt.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround in a qt bugreport (https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43366)

I set the style of the WebView the following way, and it worked:

setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"));